# Simple bearer token authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, openid-connect

I have a micro-service with REST API and I want to secure it with oidc token. This token is issued with our company authority.
The use case is that user signs in with that authority and receives a jwt token, which he sends in every request. My service should validate that token with the authority and grant access to the user based on that validation.
My question is how to do it with spring boot security, or if to you use spring boot for that at all. I looked everywhere on the internet and there are variety of use cases, but none seems to clarify how to achieve what I am trying to achieve. It seems like everybody is considering this use case too obvious to explain, but I am somehow still missing the point.

Comment: You can refer the mentioned link, I've already answered the similar question [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761800/how-to-load-private-key-from-key-file/61762117#61762117)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is article https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular

"Authorization server" is your company authority, you do not have to implement it.

You should focus on implementing "Resource server".

Also, Spring Boot comes with usage examples https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I just probably wasn't using good terminology. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you have to generate the token to connect secure API of your organization, in that case, you required the following details  `private.der` file and rest properties need to set in order to generate the token, you refer the code for an example, the code may be written in simple java but no harm to use with spring boot.
[demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761800/how-to-load-private-key-from-key-file/61762117#61762117)

```
 keyAlgorithm=RSA
    keyPath=private-stage.der
    subject=
    issuer=
    audience=
    claimKey=
    claimValue=true
    tokenExpiryFrequency=DAY
    tokenExpiryUnit=1
    clientId=
    clientSecret=
    jwtTokenUrl=
```